# basic process for implemening password salting and hashing in a web app

Tags: security, hash

I have been looking for a good explanation of how to implement a password login system in a typical website environment. I have read some great wikipedia articles and SO Q&A and blogs etc but they always seem to focus on purely generating the hash rather than the whole process of creating hash sending which parts of it, storing which parts of it, what the server side code does with it etc. If there is already a good answer on SO I apologise for reposting, and please link.

My current understanding is:

1) A new user creates a new account on your website. They enter a "password", the client side code then generates and appends a long random string "salt" to the end and generates a hash -> BCrypt(password+salt) for example. The client code then sends the full hash plus the unhashed salt to the server.

2) The server stores the full hash and the unhashed salt in the users entry in a DB.

3) During the user login they type their password which is then hashed with a salt again,

Question 1) How does the client side code generate the same 'random' salt value for each user?

Question 2) at this point does the client side code just send the full hash without the salt?

Question 3) what does the server side do with the full hash once it has received it? (simply compare the sent full hash with the stored full hash? If that's the case then can't an attacker upon breaking into the db and getting the stored full hash values just use them directly to send to the server to log in? This is based on my assumption that the log in process essentially involves the server comparing the full hash sent from the client with the full hash stored in the db.

Question 4) should passwords always be sent over secure connection? or does salting and hashing them make it ok for anyone to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the purpose of the hashing.  It is not intended to secure the password for wire transmission.  The client does not generate the hash.  the purpose of the hash is to prevent an attacker who compromises your database from being able to quickly use a pre-generated hash lookup table to determine what your user's passwords are.

A trivial example follows- as @jhoyla points out in the comments below, industrial grade production schemes are even more complex.

To create an account:

1. The client establishes a secure (encrypted, e.g. SSL) connection with the server, and sends the username and password, usually in plaintext (which is OK, because it is encrypted).
2. The server generates a random salt, appends it to the password, hashes the result, and stores the hash and the unhashed salt value.

To log in:

1. The client establishes a secure (encrypted, e.g. SSL) connection with the server, and sends the username and password, usually in plaintext (which is OK, because it is encrypted).
2. The server retrieves the salt from storage, appends it to the password, hashes it, and compares the result to the hashed password in storage.  If they match, the user is logged in.

To establish why we do this, imagine that I have successfully attacked a website's database server and downloaded the database.  I now have a list of usernames, probably email addresses, and password hashes.  If the passwords are not salted, then there is a very high probability that many of the hashes will be the same (because many people use the same weak passwords).  I know that the likelihood of one of those users having that same weak password on (for example) their email account is quite high.  So I go to work and hash the whole dictionary, plus many other likely passwords, looking for a hash that matches one of these popular ones.  If I get a hit, I've just broken a bunch of passwords.  If I was smart, I'd have generated this list in advance so that I can do it quickly.

Now imagine that the passwords are salted.  Now, even if two people use the same password, a different salt will have been generated for each of them, and the resulting hashes will be different.  I have no way of knowing which passwords are weak, common passwords, and which ones are strong passwords.  I can try my dictionary attack by appending the salt to each possible password, but the difficulty (in terms of time) of cracking a password has now gone up exponentially.

Comment: There are more complex schemes in which passwords are iteratively hashed a large number of times that can be transmitted unencrypted safely. For example a scheme might be
1. Client creates an account and hashes his password e.g. 10,000 times.
2. The server stores the hash and the number 10,000.
3. On log-in n, the client submits his password hashed 10,000 - n times.
4. The server then hashes the hash once more, compares it to the stored hash, and if it's the same replaces the stored hash with the submitted hash and decrements it's number.
This prevents someone resubmitting the hash.

Comment: Salts don't stop dictionary attacks so much because it's still very fast to do a dictionary attack against each account, even with different salts. However, with good passwords where brute force is required, it forces the attacker to brute force one account at a time, rather than all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

never ever implement it yourself! if you need it just for learning then @Chris answered you. but if you need for for a working software then don't do it. every language has security libraries and every data store (ldap, database) has password storing mechanism already implemented. use it, don't invent the wheel again because you will most probably miss some detail

Comment: I am aware of this and I agree with you. I just want to understand the process of what is going on is what the client is doing, what the client sends to the server and what the server does with this. As you say I would never implement this myself